# пытаюсь превратить код на питоне в однострочник

Tags: python

не могу засунуть это в одну строку (делаю это просто так), если это можно сделать, и если кто то знает как, помогите пожалуйста

```
import itertools as it

for i in it.permutations([int(i) for i in str(int(input()))]):
    print(''.join(list([str(a) for a in list(i)])))
```

Comment: Что это такое - ``str(int(input()))``???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, вроде работает

```
import itertools as it
print('\n'.join(''.join(a for a in x) for x in (it.permutations(i for i in input()))))
```

P.S.  Не перевожу в `int`. Нигде не формирую `list`, без [] и так работает генератор

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй :

```py
import itertools as it; [print(''.join(map(str,p))) for p in it.permutations([int(i) for i in str(int(input())))]
```